# Pointer causes access violation

Tags: c++, pointers

I've got a console application reading some char-data from the console and then puts in into a structure. This structure is used as linked list, when it's constructed, I keep one pointer pointing to the first list element and one pointer for running through the list.
What happens to me is, when I first run through my list and write its contents into the console, everything works perferctly. When I later want to set my running pointer to the lists last element, it keeps crashing with an c000005 access violation error.
I will give you the interesting parts of my code:

definition of my structure:

```
struct musikdaten {
    char interpret[150];
    char titel[150];
    struct musikdaten* next;
};
```

printing the lists content:

```
while (it != NULL) {
    cout << it->interpret << ": " << it->titel << "\n";
    cout << "next: " << it->next << "\n";
    it = it->next;
}
```

setting "it" to the lists last element:

```
while (true) {
    if (it->next == NULL) {
        cout << "Assigning some memory...\n";
        it->next = new musikdaten;
        break;
    }
    else it = it->next;
}
```

However, this last part keeps crashing when the list contains more than two elements.
Note: When a new list element is added while reading it's content from console, the next pointer is always initialized as NULL.

Comment: what do you cout `it->next`, `it->next` can be null

Comment: Put NULL pointer check everywhere even on it not just on it->next and write out messages if it is not right. I can't seem to find any error here.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the `next` member with `NULL` to indicate the end of the list:

```
it->next = new musikdaten;
it->next->next = NULL;
```

Or add a default constructor:

```
struct musikdaten {
musikdaten() { next = NULL; /*TODO: init other members*/}     
char interpret[150];
char titel[150];
struct musikdaten* next;
};
```